# best strategy to update from invalid date formats vs allow_invalid_dates

Tags: mysql, datetime

Here is the `create table` syntax from a legacy table:

```
CREATE TABLE `bais_logs` (
`lg_id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lg_machines_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'unique machine id from which they are logged in',
`lg_editdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'this will not be changed with a ping; only a logout or other edit',
`lg_acctname` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'admin1' COMMENT 'as of 2012-04-01 this has not been used',
`lg_stusername` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'the logged in user; note st_ prefix is inaccurate as it may be a contact or other object',
`lg_masterlogin` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lg_stemail` char(85) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'email address at time of login',
`lg_action` mediumint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lg_requesttype` mediumint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lg_sessionkey` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`lg_ipaddress` char(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
`lg_referrer` char(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`lg_feed` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`lg_lastping` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'last ajax ping to determine still logged in',
`lg_entertime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`lg_exittime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`lg_logouttime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`lg_id`),
KEY `lg_machines_id` (`lg_machines_id`),
KEY `lg_acctname` (`lg_acctname`),
KEY `lg_stusername` (`lg_stusername`),
KEY `lg_masterlogin` (`lg_masterlogin`),
KEY `lg_lastping` (`lg_lastping`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3074 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

You will notice a whole lot of 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in there; that is no longer a valid format and entries into this table are failing.  Even trying to change the field definitions is problematic with lots of "0" dates in there.

I am trying to update the dates to `1000-01-01 00:00:00` which is supposed to be valid, but I am getting the message:

```
update bais_logs set
lg_editdate = IF(lg_editdate=0, '1000-01-01 00:00:00', lg_editdate),

lg_lastping = IF(lg_lastping=0, '1000-01-01 00:00:00', lg_lastping),

lg_entertime = IF(lg_entertime=0, '1000-01-01 00:00:00', lg_entertime),

lg_exittime = IF(lg_exittime=0, '1000-01-01 00:00:00', lg_exittime),

lg_logouttime = IF(lg_logouttime=0, '1000-01-01 00:00:00', lg_logouttime)
----------------
MySQL said: 

#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '1000-01-01 00:00:00' for column 'lg_editdate' at row 373
```

What am I doing wrong on this? Also, how would I set `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` for now?  Is this something that is done in the mysql.ini file?

**NOTE:** from the command line I am logging into mysql as root and entering:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'traditional,allow_invalid_dates';
```

and it shows as set, but it doesn't make any difference; I still get the behavior above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Solution as this is a very small Table(3078). I suggest to create a table with the correct default values and copy the records from the existing table and then rename the table. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is ultimately what I did, thanks